# JAVA - is it possible to filter the sub elements of JSON Object that is large & recursive ??

Tags: java, jackson, gson, json

I want some help to find a quick solution for my problem. Given a json object that is large with a recursive model. I want to list the JSON sub elements & its immediate parent Object( only the sub object which satisfies the given key value condition).

```
 Ex :   
{
Object : {
   id : "0001",
   parent:"A",
   child: {
       id:"0001A",
       Country:"US",
       parent:"B",
       child:{
         id:"0001AA",
         Country:"UK",
         parent:"C",
         child:{
            id:"0000AAA",
            Country:"US",
            parent:"D",
            child:{
                .........
            }
         }
       }
   }
}
```

}

I want to list the id's of the subObject whose country is 'US' and it's parent id.. 
  is there available any readymade plugins to handle these kind of scenarios in JAVA , without using object mappers/custom class objects.. 
  Ps provide any possible idea ..

Comment: got an idea, write some code that involves a loop and a JsonObject

Comment: What do you mean by "recursive" JSON? JSON cannot be recursive. Do you mean that you have an element that refers to a parent element by way of the id?

Comment: Sorry .. it is not a recursive in nature .. what i want to mean here is   that we can not predict the json object size.. inner children may be plenty for few cases (like a loop).... 
And moreover i dont want to parse & go object by object to find each children satisfying the country code 'US'..  I just want to filter & fetch the JSON child objects with a single command..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible write code using [the Jackson Tree Model API](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel) which would traverse a JSON tree and select the nodes that satisfy criteria. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonTree2 {
    public static final String JSON = "{\"Ex\" :   {\"Object\" : {\n" +
            "   \"id\" : \"0001\",\n" +
            "   \"parent\":\"A\",\n" +
            "   \"child\": {\n" +
            "       \"id\":\"0001A\",\n" +
            "       \"Country\":\"US\",\n" +
            "       \"parent\":\"B\",\n" +
            "       \"child\":{\n" +
            "         \"id\":\"0001AA\",\n" +
            "         \"Country\":\"UK\",\n" +
            "         \"parent\":\"C\",\n" +
            "         \"child\":{\n" +
            "            \"id\":\"0000AAA\",\n" +
            "            \"Country\":\"US\",\n" +
            "            \"parent\":\"D\",\n" +
            "            \"child\":{\n" +
            "                \n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "         }\n" +
            "       }\n" +
            "\t}\n" +
            "}}}";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(JSON);
        for (JsonNode node : root.findParents("Country")) {
            if ("UK".equals(node.get("Country").asText())) {
                System.out.println(node.get("id"));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
"0001AA"
```

Comment: Your Post is very useful for me ... Also would like to know that root.findParents("Country") gives me list of JSonNodes containing the country Element only.. Is there any methods available to parse one step up and get its parent node ???  say for the above example : if Child elements Country code is "UK" , I have to print its parent ID ie. "0001A"

Comment: @user2749751 You can easily implement your own "find" method which would traverse the JsonNode tree and select the elements that meet you criteria. Take a look at the Jackson's findParent methods implementation.

Comment: Yes but all i want is one step ahead to return the parent JSONnode of the node that matches my criteria .... is it possible in JACKSON parser or any Other JSON Api ??

Comment: Could you pls put a snap of code if it is possible ?

Comment: Is it possible to find parent of a findParent node ?? with available methods in JSONRootnode.. ???